# Как заменить на нули выделенную часть двумерного массива?

Tags: c++

[image]

Есть предположение, что нужно разделить квадратную матрицу на 4 части.
Как это лучше всего сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i, j, n, m, k, sum;
   srand(time(NULL));

   cout<<"Введіть к-сть рядків матриці n = ";
   cin>>n;
   cout<<"Введіть к-сть Введіть к-сть стовпчиків матриці m = ";
   cin>>m;

   int mat[n][m];
   printf("Матриця mat( %d, %d): \n",n,m);

   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
       {
           mat[i][j] = rand()%100-50;
           printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);
       }
       cout<<endl;
   }

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = i; j < m; j++)
    {
        mat[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

printf("Матриця mat( %d, %d): \n",n,m);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);

    }
    cout<<endl;

}
cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Пока никак, поскольку вы не можете объявить массив  размерами, не определенными во время компиляции. Вы его можете создать  в куче, или  размеры должны быть константными выражениями

Answer (score -1):

1) Нужно заранее объявить размеры матрицы:

```cpp
const int line = 5;
const int column = 5;
```

или использовать только один параметр, т.к. матрица квадратная:

```cpp
const int matrixSize = 5;
```

2) Попробуйте найти зависимость между индексами строк и столбцов в данный области. Например для всех элементов выше главной диагонали выполняется неравенство 
`line < column`. Можете проходить по матрице и, если элемент попадает в выбранную область, то занулять его, иначе идти дальше.

Успехов!

Comment: По  вопросу не понятно, что матрица квадратная. Вот в чем проблема...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, у моего знакомого была такая же задача, там по условию была квадратная матрица. Тем более, что на изображении именно квадратная матрица. В любом случае, этот алгоритм будет работать и на прямоугольной матрице.